# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshak

Tags: java, rest, ssl, https

I'm using java 7 to run this code. I have added server certificate also to my local javastore, but still it is throwing below exception.
I downloaded the server certificate from firefox and exported and then imported to javaStore with keytool .

```
public class TokenizeClient {

    public static String tokenization(String data){

        byte[] credential = Base64.encodeBase64("username:password".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String encodedCrential=new String(credential);
        System.out.println("Encoded Credentials "+credential);


    /*  byte[] encoded = encodedCrential.getBytes();
        // decoding byte array into base64
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);
        String decodedCredential= new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Decode Credentials "+decodedCredential);*/

        // Tokenize request

        URL tokenize_url;
        String token = null;
        try {

            //tokenize_url = new URL(EncryptionDecryptionConstant.VTS_TOKENIZE_URL);
            tokenize_url = new URL("https://192.168.1.74/vts/rest/v2.0/tokenize");

            System.out.println("tokenizw URL :"+tokenize_url);
            //System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");

            HttpsURLConnection httpsConn=(HttpsURLConnection) tokenize_url.openConnection();


            String jStr ="{\"data\":\""+data+"\",\"tokengroup\":\"Enliven-Token-Test\",\"tokentemplate\":\"Enliven-Token-Temp\"}";
            //String jStr ="{\"data\":\"Anees\",\"tokengroup\":\"Enliven-Token-Test\",\"tokentemplate\":\"Enliven-Token-Temp\"}";

            System.out.println("input String :"+jStr);

            httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(jStr.length()));
            httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+encodedCrential);
            httpsConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpsConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpsConn.setDoInput(true);

            System.out.println("###### All header properties are set");

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(httpsConn.getOutputStream());


            output.writeBytes(jStr);
            output.close();


            BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsConn.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";
            String strResponse = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            strResponse=strResponse+line;
            }
            rd.close();
             System.out.println("********** Response ***"+strResponse);
             token = JsonPath.read(strResponse, "$.token").toString();
            httpsConn.disconnect();

            return token;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return token;   
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result =VormetricTokenizeClient.tokenization("Anees");
        System.out.println("##############  "+result);
    }
}
```

## Exception:

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
##############  null
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.ramyam.security.adapter.VormetricTokenizeClient.tokenization(VormetricTokenizeClient.java:79)
    at com.ramyam.security.adapter.VormetricTokenizeClient.main(VormetricTokenizeClient.java:210)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    ... 9 more
```

I can see my added certificate in debug console

Comment: The server closing the connection on ClientHello can be anything, like unexpected protocol version or ciphers, missing TLS extensions, wrong server setup etc. It is not related to validation of certificates. Looking at the connection close at the client side will not help much. Instead you need to look at the server side, i.e. why did the server close the connections. It is unknown what kind of server there is but hopefully you have some log files or other kind of reporting errors there.